# Radius of convergence (taylor series, calculus)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

Question states

Let $f:  \mathbf{R} \rightarrow  \mathbf{R} $ be the function given by

$f(x)=\frac {x}{4+x^2} $

Give the Taylor series of f around the point $x = 0$ and state it’s radius of convergence

my guess is $n$-th root test but i'm not sure, also please do not use intermediate calculus to solve this problem

Comment: You need to compute the series before you worry about the radius of convergence.  It's premature to try to choose between the root test or the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

A few things may help.

If $g$ has radius of convergence (ROC) $R$ then $x \mapsto x g(x)$ will have the same ROC so we can just look at $x \mapsto {1 \over 4+x^2}$.

Note that if $h(x) = {1 \over 1+x}$ we can write $g(x) = {1 \over 4}h(({x \over 2})^2)$, so if $h$ has ROC $R$ then we know that $g$ has ROC of at least
${R^2 \over 4}$.

(Full disclosure: It is possible, since $x^2 \ge 0$, that the ROC of $g$ could be larger.)

The expansion of $h$ about $x=0$ is $1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$ with a ROC of $1$,
and in this case, if $|x|=1$ the series does not converge, so the previous 
 parethetical
remark does not apply.

The series for $g$ follows from the series for $h$.